# "They tricked me for/by/of $10"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A vendor sold me some article of merchandise for $30, but the real cost of the article was only $20. Can I say:

> They tricked me for/by/of $10

I also wonder if the verb *trick* is appropriate in this context or it'd better be replaced with *cheat*.

Comment: They *cheated me **out of** $10*, they *overcharged me **by** $10*, etc.

Comment: "Scammed" is another term you might use.

Comment: Please update/clarify the OP post with the additional details found in my answer, because this is really misleading.

Comment: In a comment far below, you said it was a haggling market.  You weren't cheated or tricked, you were out-bargained.  You would have had a better question if you had explained the context -- the haggling market.  But if someone approached you on the street and said "Wanna buy a Rolex for 30 bucks?" you were tricked.

Comment: The usual exclamation (in AmE ) for this situation uses the compound verb "got taken". It may be stated using the proper tense: "I got **taken** for $10," or, in the idiomatic: "I/You/He got **took**."

Answer (score -1):

They cheated me out of $10.

They scammed me out of $10.

They scammed me for $10.

Comment: As one of the comments in my Answer pointed out, by OP actually, it's not a cheat, scam or such. It's a legit, legal, correct market price. Just one that one might find higher than the other vendor's. That doesn't make it a scam. Quite the contrary.

Comment: How again? In a free market, or any market really, you have the option of running prices higher than average, just average, or below average. Neither option makes it a cheat. I mean, there is a possible different vendor down the street then, don't make a bad purchase! It's the customer's fault for buying overpriced things, not the merchant's!

Comment: In this case though, the buyer is perfectly aware of the less overpriced, cheaper alternative elsewhere. Why not go there then? No cheating involved if someone is deliberately ignoring information that would lead to the refusal of purchasing something overpriced.

Comment: @Sakatox Sorry to respond to a deleted comment to another answer, but there is no single English with one set of rules. Each individual has a set of tules (which are not always followed in lockstep) and these individuals in general fall into rough classes, overlapping at the edges. "I'm going to hospital" and "I'm going to the hospital" are used in two different varieties: each one grammatical in one variety and ungrammatical in the other, but not both in the same variety. So a rule can be correct in one variety and incorrect in another.

Comment: My point still stands. As long as it is valid in any interpretation, you cannot deflect it as a wrong answer. Unless of course i'm seeing AmEng or such specified in the OP.

Comment: Referring to the comment on the deleted answer that the other deleted comments presumably derive from, there is a difference between "wrong" and "not idiomatic".  I said "not idiomatic".

Answer (score -2):

One can argue - in context of the example, unless someone clearly saw a pricetag indicating $20, instead of $30 - or checked/asked at all, then it's a simple purchase made. That's how haggling markets work. /semantics.

- They tricked me **for** $10.

I'd go with for, because it *can* mean what you'd expect.
There's a certain degree of ambiguity, like it could mean that you paid $10 for them to trick you - as a service or such. It could also mean someone put them up to the task and paid $10. However, in this context, with the right preceding sentences, it is perfectly valid.

Proposed alternatives in OP Question's comments are also good to use.

For more alternatives:

- They kept the $10 change.
- They short-changed my $10.
- They short-changed me by $10.

Maybe that very last alternative i just wrote?

**EDIT:** After reading that comment @Nadin, i think you're not actually looking for scam, cheat, or such. It's a general market thing. You might've bought an overpriced thing, but that **is not a trick**. You **deliberately paid** it, and ***haggling is an optional thing***.

You wasted $10, or they made you waste $10 - however, in reality, if you are saying it's a haggling/market/arguing situation where you find the price too high, then no, they didn't do anything. You made a dud then. Speaking in context, of course. This is trying to weasel out of a legit, proper purchase of something overpriced. Like buying an Apple product when you could settle for something less overpriced.

Comment: No, your last alternatives don't correspond to the context, I think. But I do see now that my example may be ambiguous. So, to clarify: I meant something like a haggling market. It has nothing to do with change or a fixed price. It's more as if a vendor persuaded me that $30 was a reasonable price, although I could buy the same article for $20 just around the corner.

Comment: Is that a typo in #2? "They short-changed __me__ $10" or "They short-changed __me by__ $10"

Comment: Not a typo, just a way to say that you might be aware of how much the change was.